# iterate through all datatable objects in a page?

Tags: javascript, foreach, google-datatable

I have a webpage that displays graphs using Google Charts.  I've created multiple DataTables as below :

```
var rttldata1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var rttldata2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var rttldata3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
...
var rttldata10 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

At a certain point, I want to do something to all of these tables with javascript.

Something like

```
for each (datatable){
    do something
}
```

Can some one point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will want to encapsulate the instantiation of each DataTable within a function to stay DRY and add to an array. Then you can loop through each object.

```
var tables = [];

function makeDataTable(options) {
  var options = options || {};
  var table = new google.visualization.DataTable(options);
  tables.push(table);
  return table; // not needed in this context, but you might want
}

// insert code that creates tables via makeDataTable({}) ...

for (var i = 0, max = tables.length; i < max; i += 1) {
  var currTable = tables[i];
  // do something with currTable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to push each datatable in an array and then map through the array?

```
var array = [];
array.push(rttldata1, rttldata2, rttldata3, ...., rttldatan);
array.map(function(datatable) { doSomething(datatable) });
```